# Memory leak in Mex

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, mex

I am doing below in a loop with `dims = [1024 768 256]`. I want to read a set of block loaded by `block_iter` (1 to 16) into a RAM of hardware. The memory call seems to display the memory leaking. Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

```
for (block_iter = 1; block_iter <= num_blocks; block_iter++)
{
    //Allocate memory to read data;
    mxArray *B= mxCreateNumericArray(3, dims, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL); // Pointer to mxArray
    mxArray *in = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

    mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "memory");
    memcpy(mxGetPr(in), &block_iter, sizeof(double)*1*1);
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &B, 1, &in, "data_feeder");

    //Call RAM_FILL
    ram_fill(d,B);

    //Deallocate memory;
    mxDestroyArray(B);
    mxDestroyArray(in);
}
```

**P.S:** the memory leak is around 192 MB each loop which is exactly the amount of data in array `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (block_iter = 1; block_iter <= num_blocks; block_iter++)
{    
        mxArray *B;// = mxCreateNumericArray(3,dims,mxUINT8_CLASS,mxREAL); //Pointer to mxArray
        mxArray *ppLhs[1];
        mxArray *in = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

//         mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,0,NULL,"memory");
        memcpy(mxGetPr(in), &block_iter, sizeof(double)*1*1);
        mexCallMATLAB(1, ppLhs,1,&in,"data_feeder");
        B = ppLhs[0];
        //Call RAM_FILL
        ram_fill(d,B,block_iter);
//         mexPrintf("BlockIter %d\n",(int)block_iter);
        //Deallocate memory;
        mxDestroyArray(B);
        mxDestroyArray(in);
}
```

I did this as the mxCallMatlab worked fine with an array of mxArray *, this works fine without memory leak. If there's any elegant solution please let me know.